# .Net Core can't connect to MariaDB running in docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm running MariaDB 10.3 in a docker container exposed on port 5027. I can connect no problem from [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) on localhost:5027. However, .Net Core fails to connect. I am running my .net application directly on the windows host (not in a docker container).

My connection string looks like

`Server=localhost:5027;Database=devdb;user=****;password=****`

(For the record, I have also tried 127.0.0.1:5027 with no success)

I'm able to connect to MaraDB running in a virtual machine in HyperV. Why does it fail to connect to my docker container while DataGrip can connect with no issues?

I'm running Docker for Windows, connecting from an ASP.Net Core 2.2 application. My MariaDB image is `mariadb:10.3`

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: @DavidMaze This question is not the same. Please see in the question where it says "I am running my .net application directly on the windows host"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The connection string should be `Server=localhost;Port=5027;Database=devdb;user=****;password=****`

not

`Server=localhost:5027;Database=devdb;user=****;password=****`